# App opening in vertical mode, not in horizontal mode

Tags: javascript, android, css, html

I created an android app by using HTML5, javascript and phonegap. I got the final apk. But when I install the apk in mobile and open it, it opens in vertical mode. But I want it to be opened in horizontal mode. How can I do that?

Comment: Should the app be able to rotate from landscape to portrait or do you want it to stay in landscape?

Comment: It should stay in landscape

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the [Cordova config.xml file doc](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/config_ref_index.md.html#The%20config.xml%20File) once.

You basically have to add/modify a **preference** in config.xml.

> Orientation allows you to lock orientation and prevent the interface from rotating in response to changes in orientation. Possible values are default, landscape, or portrait.

```
<preference name="Orientation" value="landscape" />
```

Comment: Where is this cordova config.xml file in `ubuntu`?

Comment: That link says that it can be found in top level of directory. But I'm using build.phonegap.com and pulling the code into build.phonegap.com via github. How can I locate `Cordova config.xml`?

Comment: add it to the same level as your index.html file ( [see more](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_basics.md.html#The%20Basics) )

Comment: Great, it worked. Is it possible to render the page by using `config.xml` so that it can be opened smoothly in various mobiles?

Comment: sorry i do not understand what do mean by render the page by using config.xml

Comment: I created HTML5, CSS3 and javascript app and I got apk through build.phonegap.com. If I install that apk in mobiles, all images and text will be mixed up. It won't exactly be same as web version. Is it possible to fix it by using config.xml?

Comment: no, i think you cannot fix it using config.xml but you can always load dynamic images and text using ajx from your remote server.